# Which xdg-desktop-portal am I currently using?

Tags: debian, command-line, gnome, xdg

On my machine, I have multiple xdg-desktop-portal instances:

```
$ ls -la /usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals
.rw-r--r-- 100 root 23 Mar 14:48 gnome-keyring.portal
.rw-r--r--  99 root 20 Mar 02:25 gnome-shell.portal
.rw-r--r-- 548 root 18 Oct  2022 gnome.portal
.rw-r--r-- 495 root 29 Nov  2022 gtk.portal
```

I'm having trouble determining which one is currently in use.

What command can I use to find out which xdg-desktop-portal I am using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn’t *one* portal that’s currently in use: portals generally handle a subset of [the available interfaces](https://flatpak.github.io/xdg-desktop-portal/#idm28). Thus on my system,

- `gnome-keyring.portal` says that it should be used for GNOME, and provides [`org.freedesktop.portal.Secret`](https://flatpak.github.io/xdg-desktop-portal/#gdbus-org.freedesktop.portal.Secret)
- `gnome-shell.portal` says that it should be used for GNOME, and provides [`org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Access`](https://flatpak.github.io/xdg-desktop-portal/#gdbus-org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Access)
- `gtk.portal` again says that it should be used for GNOME, and provides a number of interfaces such as the file chooser, the print dialog, etc.

The desktop environment currently in use is determined by the `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` environment variable.

Thus a given request will be handled by one of the available portals, depending on the current desktop environment and the requested interface. In most setups, none of the portals overlap, and each will be used as appropriate — there’s nothing to choose between.

Answer (score 3):

[Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Desktop_Portal) Says:

> Multiple backends can be installed, and they are located in /usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals/*.portal. Each portal backend file contains a list of interfaces that it can handle, and the desktop environments that it can be used in. When a request is made, xdg-desktop-portal will use the XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP environment variable to determine which backend it will use for the request. If more than one backend can be used for the current desktop, the first one in alphabetical order is chosen. If no backend for the current desktop can handle the interface, no backend is available for the current desktop, or xdg-desktop-portal can't determine the current desktop, then it will choose the first portal in alphabetical order between all of the installed portals that support the requested interface.

The value of `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` corresponds to the desktop environment or session you are currently using with:

`echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Get more detailed information about the active `xdg-desktop-portal` instance:

`xdg-desktop-portal version`

Comment: regarding "`xdg-desktop-portal version`" - is this an Arch-specific executable/command? For Debian 12 (as the question is tagged), I can't find an `xdg-desktop-portal` executable on `$PATH` which can be executed with a `version` **parameter**. Alas, `/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal --version` works (notice `--version` **flag**), and returns e.g. `xdg-desktop-portal 1.16.0`.

Comment: ... and to find out portal *backend* versions, for example, `/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome --version` and `/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk --version`.